# COUNT from previous day is being excluded if the COUNT for current day is 0

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have a measure that counts the number of traces for the most recent day and the day before that. The dates are always linear. Meaning, it goes from 2/21/2024 to 2/20/2024 to 2/19/2024, to 2/16/2024 - it skips weekend dates. The measures Total is correct, but the measure filters out and ShipVia that doesn't have a a COUNT for the current day. I've attached pictures, that should make more sense. I attached a picture of what the end goal is. I also included my measures below. Also, attached is the CASE WHEN for the LAG Date. To replicate this issue, create a line graph with the count of invoices in the y-axis and [Trace Start Dt Alt] in the x-axis and select the date 1/17/2024. This will replicate the problem.

[image: End Goal]

[image: Current Table]

This is Current Date :

```
Traces = 
VAR CurrentDate = MAX('Traces R5'[Trace Start Dt Alt])
RETURN 
        CALCULATE(
            COUNT('Traces R5'[Invoice]),
            FILTER(
                ALLEXCEPT('Traces R5', 'Traces R5'[Region], 'Traces R5'[ShipVia]), 
                'Traces R5'[Trace Start Dt Alt] = CurrentDate
    ))
```

This is PreviousDate :

```
Previous Day Traces = 
VAR CurrentDate = MAX('Traces R5'[Trace Start Dt Alt])
VAR PreviousDate = MAX('Traces R5'[LagDate])

RETURN 
        CALCULATE(
            COUNT('Traces R5'[Invoice]),
            FILTER(
                ALLEXCEPT('Traces R5', 'Traces R5'[Region], 'Traces R5'[ShipVia]), 
                'Traces R5'[Trace Start Dt Alt] = PreviousDate
            )

    )
```

Using SQL :

```
    , CASE 
        WHEN LEFT(DATENAME(DW,CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10), S.MAINTDATE, 101) AS DATE)), 3) IN ('Mon') 
            THEN DATEADD(DAY, -3, CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10), S.MAINTDATE, 101) AS DATE))
        WHEN LEFT(DATENAME(DW,CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10), S.MAINTDATE, 101) AS DATE)), 3) IN ('Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri') 
           THEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10), S.MAINTDATE, 101) AS DATE))
      END AS LagDate
```

I tried a various combinations of measures, custom columns, and SQL but I can't get those ShipVias to show

Comment: Can you share your input data ?

Comment: @AmiraBedhiafi Is there a way I can attach an excel file? Or what would be the best way to share my input data?

Comment: You can use dropbox for example

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/1hz11n8hf9tjzbe2heb3k/Input-Data.xlsx?rlkey=h40ysm2bsc32lfnnmstamlspo&dl=0

Here is the link to the dropbox! @AmiraBedhiafi

Comment: Are you using any calendar table ?

Comment: No calendar table @AmiraBedhiafi

Comment: Why not ? it is necessary in your case

Comment: I thought I didn't need it so I didn't create/import one. How is it necessary in this case?